# 5-color graph problem

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

I need to demonstrate that a graph that doesn't have odd disjunctive circuits is a five color graph. This is indeed for a homework. I need some suggestions on how to approach this problem. Any help is welcomed.

Comment: I assume by "doesn't have odd disjunctive circuits" you that the graph "does not contain two vertex-disjoint odd circuits"?

Comment: and "is a five colour graph" means its vertices can be coloured with five colours in such a way that adjacent vertices have different colours?

Comment: @ChrisEagle Yes, that's what it means

Comment: @ChrisGodsil Yes, it doesn't contain two vertex-disjoint odd circuits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is an odd cycle, select a shortest one and remove all its vertices. The remaining graph is bipartite and can be coloured with $A$ and $B$. Put the removed cycle back in and colour it with $C$, $D$ and $E$. Why can there be no colour conflict?

Comment: Is it because the shortest odd cycle is made out of 3 vertices and that cycle can be colored with 3 colors different from the 2 colored remaining bipartite graph?

Answer (score 2):

There's also a pretty nice alternative solution by contradiction, which is as follows:

Assume that this is not true, so $\chi(G) \geq 6$ and consider a minimal coloring. There must be at least six colors in the graph; consider the subgraph induced by vertices of three of these colors. It contains an odd cycle, else this subgraph would be bipartite and we could obtain a better coloring by only using 2 colors. Similarly, take another three colors and repeat the same reasoning to get another odd cycle. These two cycles are vertex-disjoint, because none of their vertices have the same color.